# Action Image Capture causing blurred images when viewing

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

When taking a picture in an android app I have it is, displaying blurry/reduced images, I do realize this will be from the Bitmap .....data.getExtras().get the ("data") code but anything else I have changed has not worked, the displayed image is still blurry.

How can I get it to display a full res picture?

Camera Intent Code

```
private void cameraIntent()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
```

On Activity Code

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY)
            onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
        else if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            onCaptureImageResult(data);
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

and finally the oncaptureImageResult   - where I believe I am going wrong for the blurry image

```
private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    imageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try WeakReference, this will return the clear image without reduced quality

```
  WeakReference<Bitmap> result1 = new WeakReference<Bitmap>(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src,
            src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), false).copy(
            Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true));
Bitmap bm=result1.get(); //Set this bitmap to any imageview that you want to display your image.
```

put above code in onCaptureImageResult() method for ex.

```
private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
WeakReference<Bitmap> result1 = new WeakReference<Bitmap>(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(thumbnail,
        thumbnail.getWidth(), thumbnail.getHeight(), false).copy(
        Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, true));
   Bitmap bm=result1.get();
   imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);}
```

Comment: onCaptureImageResult() Put there

Comment: well i have update my code, let me know if its not work

Answer (score 1):

try this , this will return the exact image without reduced quality ..

```
Uri u;

 private void cameraIntent() {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String stvalue = Long.toString(time);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        File output = new File(dir, stvalue);
        u = Uri.fromFile(output);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, u);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}

 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable("file_uri", u);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    u = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
}
```

then in onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {          
        camerastore(u);
        break;
    } else {
        utils.Toast("Error in importing file");
    }
}


void camerastore(Uri u) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    File pictureFile = new File("yourpath/image.jpg");

    try {
        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), u);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos)
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can i ask where camerapath has come from?

Comment: I have edited , I just copied it from my project , I faced similar issue .. this code works good for me .. There may be some  unwanted codes , don't bother it , I just posted for  you to understand the concept

Comment: Work fine for me :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

change this line.

```
 thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
```

to

```
 thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to change anything unfortunately, doesn't change any of the resolutions when viewing it on a phone

Answer (score 0):

You are compressing the image too much by using `JPEG` compress format with a 10% extra loss of image quality by specifying `90` in your quality. And basically you do a lossy compression. To do a loseless compression you should opt PNG compress format with 100% quality. You can do it like below:

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
```

And also another piece of advice. Create the image file in your `cameraIntent()` method itself with the help of `File Provider` and in `onActivity` just display the image from file. It provides great quality.

Comment: @swativishnoi Could you explain your issue?

Comment: ByteArrayOutputStream and compressed with 100 did't work for me, I still get image blur/compressed.
But open capture image intent with uri work fine for me.  onActivityResult get image from fileUri directly. 

   takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

Comment: @swativishnoi Thats the expected result. If you need the full resolution of the mobile's camera image, you need to fetch from fileUri only.